# In PHP is it ok to use ?> TEXT <?php instead of echo()

Tags: php, html

For example:

I have a php file like this:

```
<?php
 if ($var == true)
 {
   ?>
     <p>Some text here</p>
   <?php
 }
 else
 {
   ?>
     <p>Some different text</p>
   <?php
 }
?>
```

Is this bad to do, or is it better to use echo() like this:

```
<?php
 if ($var == true)
 {
   echo ("<p>Some text here</p>");
 }
 else
 {
   echo ("<p>Some different text</p>");
 }
?>
```

I find it much easier to use `?> HTML CODE <?php`

But does it have any compatibility, or performance issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a big difference, so except in cases where you're actually experiencing performance problems you should do what is easier for you or your team to read and write.

If you're concerned about `echo` performance, you should use [single-quoted](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) strings if you don't need the additional interpretation features of double-quoted strings. They should be a bit faster.

Comment: Thanks, though I was concerned about the `?> HTML CODE <?php` performance, not the echo performance.

Comment: @Isaac See the first paragraph. It just doesn't matter much.